# How to use vectorized document output by Mahout seq2sparse in Apache Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mahout

The Mahout `seq2sparse` generates a bunch of sequenceFiles as fully described [here](https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/creating-vectors-from-text.html). I'd like to use the vectorized documents which has this format: < Text, VectorWritable > (docID, TF-IDF Vector) and create a `JavaRDD<Vector>` out of he TF-IDF Vector. Could someone guide me through that?

Answer (score 0):

This information is readily available [in the documentation](https://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/spark-naive-bayes.html).

> Preprocessing: For a set of Sequence File Formatted documents in PATH_TO_SEQUENCE_FILES the mahout seq2sparse command performs the
>   TF-IDF transformations (-wt tfidf option) and L2 length normalization
>   (-n 2 option) as follows:
>
> ```
> $ mahout seq2sparse 
>   -i ${PATH_TO_SEQUENCE_FILES} 
>   -o ${PATH_TO_TFIDF_VECTORS} 
>   -nv 
>   -n 2
>   -wt tfidf
>
> Training: The model is then trained using mahout spark-trainnb. The default is to train a Bayes model. The -c option is given to train
> ```
>
> a CBayes model:
>
> ```
> $ mahout spark-trainnb
>   -i ${PATH_TO_TFIDF_VECTORS} 
>   -o ${PATH_TO_MODEL}
>   -ow 
>   -c
>
> Label Assignment/Testing: Classification and testing on a holdout set can then be performed via mahout spark-testnb. Again, the -c
> ```
>
> option indicates that the model is CBayes:
>
> ```
> $ mahout spark-testnb 
>   -i ${PATH_TO_TFIDF_TEST_VECTORS}
>   -m ${PATH_TO_MODEL} 
>   -ow 
>   -c
> ```

Looking at the `mahout` [command script](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/bin/mahout#L275), we see that it's actually using the `org.apache.mahout.drivers.TrainNBDriver` class. We're interested in the [parts using](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/mahout/drivers/TrainNBDriver.scala#L75-L95) the `TFIDF` vectors of type `<Text, VectorWritable>`:

```
  /** Read the training set from inputPath/part-x-00000 sequence file of form <Text,VectorWritable> */
  private def readTrainingSet: DrmLike[_]= {
    val inputPath = parser.opts("input").asInstanceOf[String]
    val trainingSet= drm.drmDfsRead(inputPath)
    trainingSet
  }

  override def process(): Unit = {
    start()

    val complementary = parser.opts("trainComplementary").asInstanceOf[Boolean]
    val outputPath = parser.opts("output").asInstanceOf[String]

    val trainingSet = readTrainingSet
    val (labelIndex, aggregatedObservations) = SparkNaiveBayes.extractLabelsAndAggregateObservations(trainingSet)
    val model = NaiveBayes.train(aggregatedObservations, labelIndex)

    model.dfsWrite(outputPath)

    stop()
  }
```

If we look closer, we see that the input is being transformed by the `drm.drmDfsRead(inputPath)` call. This will then be transformed like so (example from the [SparkEngine bindings](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/spark/src/main/scala/org/apache/mahout/sparkbindings/SparkEngine.scala#L135-L149))

```
  /**
   * Load DRM from hdfs (as in Mahout DRM format)
   *
   * @param path
   * @param sc spark context (wanted to make that implicit, doesn't work in current version of
   *           scala with the type bounds, sorry)
   *
   * @return DRM[Any] where Any is automatically translated to value type
   */
  def drmDfsRead (path: String, parMin:Int = 0)(implicit sc: DistributedContext): CheckpointedDrm[_] = {

    val drmMetadata = hdfsUtils.readDrmHeader(path)
    val k2vFunc = drmMetadata.keyW2ValFunc

    // Load RDD and convert all Writables to value types right away (due to reuse of writables in
    // Hadoop we must do it right after read operation).
    val rdd = sc.sequenceFile(path, classOf[Writable], classOf[VectorWritable], minPartitions = parMin)

        // Immediately convert keys and value writables into value types.
        .map { case (wKey, wVec) => k2vFunc(wKey) -> wVec.get()}

    // Wrap into a DRM type with correct matrix row key class tag evident.
    drmWrap(rdd = rdd, cacheHint = CacheHint.NONE)(drmMetadata.keyClassTag.asInstanceOf[ClassTag[Any]])
  }
```

Comment: So I use ``seq2sparse`` to convert the txt documents to vectorized documents as you mentioned in the first part of the post, but I got confused about the second part. Which part of the code I should use to convert the vectorized documents into JavaRDD<Vector>?Besides, as the size of my vectorized documents is big, I need to do this conversion in Hadoop.